# Have latex (bold) and variable in the legend of a figure

Tags: matlab

I have two lines in one figure, one is called error, and the other is typed by latex form as well as the second element of array `x` (for example), but I tried to use sprintf, but the results are weird

[image]

```
figure
plot(rand(1,10)) ;
hold on
plot(rand(1,10)) ;
x=[1.1, 2.1, 3.1]
legend( 'Error',sprintf('\bf[$\bf\frac{t v_p}{r_{well}}$] (\bf$\Pi_1$) = %f', x(2)),  'Location','best','Interpreter','latex' )
```

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the use in sprintf that is probably what messes things up, and just used str2num where it mattered. I also didnt understand your double usage of bold font (sprintf('\bf[$\bf\fr) so I wrote the following ti my understanding:  :

```
legend( 'Error',[' $$\bf\frac{t v_p}{r_{well}}$$  (\bf$$\Pi_1$$)=',num2str(x(2))],  'Location','best','Interpreter','latex' )
```

you can change the `$$` to a single `$` sign to make everything more compact, nothing dramatic, but I thought the bigger latex version will be more legible.

[image]